# Counting pattern in scala list

Tags: scala

My list looks like the following: `List(Person,Invite,Invite,Person,Invite,Person...)`. I am trying to match based on a `inviteCountRequired`, meaning that the `Invite` objects following the `Person` object in the list is variable. What is the best way of doing this?  My match code so far looks like this:

```
aList match { 
     case List(Person(_,_,_),Invitee(_,_,_),_*) => ...
     case _ => ...
}
```

First stack question, please go easy on me.

Comment: I would not keep this in one list. Either use a map (Person -> Seq[Invite]) or create a new case class PI(p: Person, is: Seq[Invite]) and have List[PI].

Comment: Thanks Rado.  And if I had to keep it in one list and wanted a fancy one liner? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your tips.  I ended up creating another case class:

```
case class BallotInvites(person:Person,invites:List[Any])
```

Then, I populated it from the original list:

```
def constructBallotList(ballots:List[Any]):List[BallotInvites] ={

  ballots.zipWithIndex.collect {
      case (iv:Ballot,i) =>{
                        BallotInvites(iv,
                          ballots.distinct.takeRight(ballots.distinct.length-(i+1)).takeWhile({
                            case y:Invitee => true
                            case y:Person =>true
                            case y:Ballot => false})
                          )}

  }}
val l = Ballot.constructBallotList(ballots)
```

Then to count based on `inviteCountRequired`, I did the following:

```
val count = l.count(b=>if ((b.invites.count(x => x.isInstanceOf[Person]) / contest.inviteCountRequired)>0) true else false )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
val aList = List(Person(1), Invite(2), Invite(3), Person(2), Invite(4), Person(3), Invite(6), Invite(7))
```

Then index each location in the list and select `Person` instances,

```
val persons = (aList zip Stream.from(0)).filter {_._1.isInstanceOf[Person]}
```

namely, `List((Person(1),0), (Person(2),3), (Person(3),5))` . Define then sublists where the lower bound corresponds to a `Person` instance,

```
val intervals = persons.map{_._2}.sliding(2,1).toArray
res31: Array[List[Int]] = Array(List(0, 3), List(3, 5))
```

Construct sublists,

```
val latest = aList.drop(intervals.last.last)  // last Person and Invitees not paired
val associations = intervals.map { case List(pa,pb,_*) => b.slice(pa,pb) } ++ latest
```

Hence the result looks like

```
Array(List(Person(1), Invite(2), Invite(3)), List(Person(2), Invite(4)), List(Person(3), Invite(6), Invite(7)))
```

Now,

```
associations.map { a => 
  val person = a.take(1)
  val invitees = a.drop(1) 
  // ...
}
```

This approach may be seen as a variable size sliding.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the domain but you should only need to iterate once to construct a list of person + invites tuple.

```
sealed trait PorI
case class P(i: Int) extends PorI
case class I(i: Int) extends PorI

val l: List[PorI] = List(P(1), I(1), I(1), P(2), I(2), P(3), P(4), I(4))

val res = l.foldLeft(List.empty[(P, List[I])])({ case (res, t) =>
  t match {
    case p @ P(_) => (p, List.empty[I]) :: res
    case i @ I(_) => {
      val head :: tail = res
      (head._1, i :: head._2) :: tail
    }
  }
})

res // List((P(4),List(I(4))), (P(3),List()), (P(2),List(I(2))), (P(1),List(I(1), I(1))))
```

Comment: Should probably ``res match { case Nil => res; case head :: tail...`` in ``case i @ I(_)`` incase the list starts with ``I``'s